# ReadPixels from WebGL canvas

Tags: webgl

I am trying to save an animation which is created with WebGL on [this page](http://www.thevirtualheart.org/webgl/DS_SIAM/4v_minimal_model.html). I'd like to store the `RGBA` values of the animation as an array on my hard drive. Therefore, I tried to use the `readPixels` method to access the data in javascript to save them. But there are always just zeros written into the array.

I tried this code to read the data from the canvas `c`

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

How can I solve the problem? Are there other ways to save the RGBA data of the canvas' animation on my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

are you reading directly after rendering as in

```
render();
gl.readPixels()
```

or are you reading in some other event? If you're reading in another event then the drawingBuffer is being cleared as per the spec.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534528/128511

Comment: I tried to use my by executing it the the web developer console of chrome. Can you tell me the best way to collect every 20th frame of the animation?

Comment: count frames in your animation loop `framecount++;if (!(framecount % 20)) gl.readPixels([..])` ?

Comment: Reading in the dev console is "in some other event" therefore it will be cleared. See the link in the answer.