# Reading From WebGL Canvas Seems To Work Inconsistently

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have this really weird situation where I tried to read out pixels from a WebGL canvas, which didn't work.  Then I wrote another version of the same program just without classes, and for some reason it works here.  Maybe I did some very basic mistake, but I really cannot spot the (semantic) difference between those two.

In the following snippet, I (Firefox 88.0 on Linux 5.11.15-arch1-2) see the console printing 128 and 0, the 128 stemming from the code outside of the class, which seems correct, as the shader is drawing 0.5 for every pixel and channel, and the 0 stemming from the code inside the class.

[EDIT] I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156971/webgl-readpixels-is-always-returning-0-0-0-0) question, but they are talking about the read having to occur in the same event as the draw, which is, as far as I can tell, true for both of my cases (two consecutive lines).  Also they are talking about an on-screen canvas, while I rendered to a framebuffer, not sure whether that makes a difference, but I assumed framebuffers to be more persistent.

```js
class Gpgpu {
  constructor(w, h, vs, fs, ans, uns) {
    this.gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
    this.gl.canvas.width = w;
    this.gl.canvas.height = h;
    this.gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.gl.createFramebuffer());
    this.out = new Uint8Array(w * h * 4);
  }
  spg(vs, fs, ans, uns) {
    let p = this.gl.createProgram();
    for (let ss of [
      { t: this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, d: vs },
      { t: this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, d: fs }
    ]) {
      let s = this.gl.createShader(ss.t);
      this.gl.shaderSource(s, ss.d);
      this.gl.compileShader(s);
      this.gl.attachShader(p, s);
    }
    this.gl.linkProgram(p);
    this.gl.useProgram(p);
    this.als = {};
    for (let an of ans) {
      this.als[an] = {
        l: this.gl.getAttribLocation(p, an),
        b: this.gl.createBuffer()
      };
    }
    this.uls = {};
    for (let un of uns) {
      this.uls[un] = this.gl.getUniformLocation(p, un);
    }
  }
  sad(n, ads) {
    this.n = n;
    for (let an in ads) {
      let al = this.als[an];
      let ad = ads[an];
      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, al.b);
      this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        Float32Array.from(ad),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
      );
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al.l);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(al.l, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  drw() {
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.n);
  }
}

class Cloth {
  constructor(w, h) {
    this.gpu = new Gpgpu(w, h);
    this.tex = this.gpu.gl.createTexture();
    this.gpu.spg(
      document.getElementById("vs").innerHTML,
      document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML,
      ["a_position"],
      []
    );
    this.gpu.sad(6, {
      a_position: [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
    });
    this.gpu.gl.bindTexture(this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.tex);
    this.gpu.gl.texImage2D(
      this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      w,
      h,
      0,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      this.gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      null
    );
  }
  t() {
    this.gpu.gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      this.gpu.gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
      this.gpu.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
      this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      this.tex,
      0
    );
    this.gpu.drw();
    this.gpu.gl.readPixels(
      0,
      0,
      this.w,
      this.h,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      this.gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      this.gpu.out
    );
    console.log(this.gpu.out[0]);
  }
}

const w = 10;
const h = 10;
const gpu = new Gpgpu(w, h);
const tex = gpu.gl.createTexture();

gpu.spg(
  document.getElementById("vs").innerHTML,
  document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML,
  ["a_position"],
  []
);
gpu.sad(6, {
  a_position: [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
});
gpu.gl.bindTexture(gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gpu.gl.texImage2D(
  gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
  0,
  gpu.gl.RGBA,
  w,
  h,
  0,
  gpu.gl.RGBA,
  gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  null
);
gpu.gl.framebufferTexture2D(
  gpu.gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
  gpu.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
  gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
  tex,
  0
);
gpu.drw();
gpu.gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gpu.gl.RGBA, gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gpu.out);
console.log(gpu.out[0]);

new Cloth(10, 10).t();
```

```html
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vs">
  attribute vec4 a_position;
              
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
  }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fs">precision highp float;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I already saw that, but I don't think it fits to my problem, as in my case I'm doing `readPixels` immedeately after `drawArrays` in both cases (inside class and outside).  Also, I'm rendering to a framebuffer, in the question it's unclear whether a framebuffer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple typo, you never defined `this.w` and `this.h` properties to your Cloth instance, but in `t()`, when doing the `readPixel` call, you try to use it.

Simply define these in your constructor and you're good to go.

```js
class Gpgpu {
  constructor(w, h, vs, fs, ans, uns) {
    this.gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
    this.gl.canvas.width = w;
    this.gl.canvas.height = h;
    this.gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.gl.createFramebuffer());
    this.out = new Uint8Array(w * h * 4);
  }
  spg(vs, fs, ans, uns) {
    let p = this.gl.createProgram();
    for (let ss of [
      { t: this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, d: vs },
      { t: this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, d: fs }
    ]) {
      let s = this.gl.createShader(ss.t);
      this.gl.shaderSource(s, ss.d);
      this.gl.compileShader(s);
      this.gl.attachShader(p, s);
    }
    this.gl.linkProgram(p);
    this.gl.useProgram(p);
    this.als = {};
    for (let an of ans) {
      this.als[an] = {
        l: this.gl.getAttribLocation(p, an),
        b: this.gl.createBuffer()
      };
    }
    this.uls = {};
    for (let un of uns) {
      this.uls[un] = this.gl.getUniformLocation(p, un);
    }
  }
  sad(n, ads) {
    this.n = n;
    for (let an in ads) {
      let al = this.als[an];
      let ad = ads[an];
      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, al.b);
      this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        Float32Array.from(ad),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
      );
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al.l);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(al.l, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  drw() {
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.n);
  }
}

class Cloth {
  constructor(w, h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.gpu = new Gpgpu(w, h);
    this.tex = this.gpu.gl.createTexture();
    this.gpu.spg(
      document.getElementById("vs").innerHTML,
      document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML,
      ["a_position"],
      []
    );
    this.gpu.sad(6, {
      a_position: [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
    });
    this.gpu.gl.bindTexture(this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.tex);
    this.gpu.gl.texImage2D(
      this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      w,
      h,
      0,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      this.gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      null
    );
  }
  t() {
    this.gpu.gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      this.gpu.gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
      this.gpu.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
      this.gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      this.tex,
      0
    );
    this.gpu.drw();
    this.gpu.gl.readPixels(
      0,
      0,
      this.w,
      this.h,
      this.gpu.gl.RGBA,
      this.gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      this.gpu.out
    );
    console.log(this.gpu.out[0]);
  }
}

const w = 10;
const h = 10;
const gpu = new Gpgpu(w, h);
const tex = gpu.gl.createTexture();

gpu.spg(
  document.getElementById("vs").innerHTML,
  document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML,
  ["a_position"],
  []
);
gpu.sad(6, {
  a_position: [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
});
gpu.gl.bindTexture(gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gpu.gl.texImage2D(
  gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
  0,
  gpu.gl.RGBA,
  w,
  h,
  0,
  gpu.gl.RGBA,
  gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  null
);
gpu.gl.framebufferTexture2D(
  gpu.gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
  gpu.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
  gpu.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
  tex,
  0
);
gpu.drw();
gpu.gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gpu.gl.RGBA, gpu.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gpu.out);
console.log(gpu.out[0]);

new Cloth(10, 10).t();
```

```html
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vs">
  attribute vec4 a_position;
              
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
  }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fs">precision highp float;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing :)  Thanks so much and have fun with your bounty!

Comment: I made it a Community Wiki because I don't want to gain any "rep" from it. However bounties do go to the main author of CW... So if there is a way (I don't remember the UI when placing a bounty on its own question) for you to not award the bounty and maybe cancel it, that would be great.

Comment: I think I cannot undo the bounty, but unchecking your answer as the accepted one, I think the bounty will go into the void.  Will recheck the anwer after the bounty expired.