# readPixels from WebGL2RenderContext returns only black pixels

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

So there is a game online that uses WebGL2 and WebAssembly. My goal is to interact with the game by script. It uses pointers internally which makes it hard to read data from the game data. That's why I decided to go over the UI using the WebGL context. I'm very new to WebGL, graphics and rendering in general and have no idea what I'm actually doing.

I've found the canvas and can execute methods on it. My first step is to take screenshots of areas using WebGL that I may use to analyze parts of the UI. For that I'm using `WebGLRenderingContext#readPixels`. Here's a snippet reading the whole canvas and saving its' pixels as RGBA:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
const pixels = new Uint8Array(ctx.drawingBufferWidth * ctx.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
ctx.readPixels(0, 0, ctx.drawingBufferWidth, ctx.drawingBufferHeight, ctx.RGBA, ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
// Returns only black / white
pixels.findIndex(pixel => pixel !== 0 && pixel !== 255); // -1
```

So in this case, there are only black pixels, all 4-tuples equal (0,0,0,255). A method to draw those pixels in a temporary canvas and download its' ImageData as png creates a black image.

What's the reason behind this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webgl readpixels is always returning 0,0,0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156971/webgl-readpixels-is-always-returning-0-0-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons the WebGl's drawing buffer gets cleared after drawing. https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.2

Any calls to `readPixels()` will just return empty data.

To keep it's content you need to set the `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag to true wen getting the drawing context via the getContext("webgl") function.

So change this

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
```

to

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl2", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even with using the flag, the array returns -1 when searching for other color value index. If more context is needed: I'm trying to use this on https://universe.flyff.com/play . You can run the game without registering. After that open dev tools, disable all breakpoints and paste this snippet into the console

Comment: The flag must be set on the context the rendering is actually happening. If you just paste your snippet into the devtools your merely creating a second context with no relation to the first.